# Объясните что за параметр в REST api?

Tags: php, api

У меня есть пример инструкция по созданию REST Api. 
Я не понимаю что за обязательный параметр мне нужно обрабатывать.
**_method: обязательное поле, со значением “patch”, без кавычек**
Объясните пожалуйста что это за параметр?
Все параметры:

```
    URL: {service}/photo/{ID}
Method: POST 
Data params:
●   _method: обязательное поле, со значением “patch”, без кавычек
●   name – необязательное
●   photo – необязательное, измененная фотография в формате base64
Success response
●   Code: 200 OK
●   Content:
○   id – уникальный идентификатор фотографии
○   name – название фотографии
○   url – абсолютная ссылка на фотографию (с http://)
Error Response (ошибка валидации): 
●   Code: 422 Unprocessable entity
●   Content - объект, где ключи - это поля, которые не прошли валидацию, а их значения - текст ошибки валидации
Error Response (Ошибка доступа) - В случае, если пользователь пытается изменить не свою фотографию, ему возвращаются следующие параметры: 
●   Code: 403 Forbidden
```

Comment: `$_POST['_method']`

Comment: У вас конфликт - метод либо POST, либо PATCH. Читайте описание этих типов методов в Интернете (https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) о том, как их рекомендовано использовать.